# Inserting data from one table to the next in sql

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have two tables with fields as shown below :-

tbl_emp --> id(auto generate, auto increment, primary key),name, dob
tbl_login --> id(refers to id in tbl_emp, primary key), password

I have a web form which reads the name, password and date of birth(dob), and a submit button. On pressing the submit button, the data is inserted into the first table, and also to the second table. It would be easy to insert data to the second column if I had a way to access the "id" field from the first table.

The query I have is :-

```
insert into tbl_emp (name,dob) values(@name, @dob);
insert into tbl_login (id,password) values((select id from tbl_emp where id=(select id from tbl_emp where id=id)), @password)
```

The problem that I encounter with the above coeds is :

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: Hay, how use this insert into tbl_login (id,password) values((select MAX(id) from tbl_emp where name=@name AND dob=@dob), @password)

Comment: @Thiha The problem with the query you said is that, there can be (may be) different people who may have same name and same dob.

Comment: yep correct. So, you may be use First INSERT then SELECT (id) then INSERT. Based on MSSQL, before your first transaction is complete, it will be read lock or write lock.

Comment: That sure looks like you're storing the password in plaintext. **Don't do that!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`SCOPE_IDENTIY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) function:

```
insert into tbl_emp (name,dob) values(@name, @dob);

insert into tbl_login (id,password) 
select id, @password 
from   tbl_emp 
where  id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks for the link to scope_identity() in ms.